# Local structure of symplectic manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

Algebraic geometry, in a naive setting, could be described as the study of spaces that locally are the solutions of systems of polynomial equations.

Similarly, locally any smooth manifolds can be described as the zero set of some smooth functions (If I recall well this is an exercise in chapter 3 of Pollack ). Hence differential topology could be described as the study of spaces that are locally the solutions of a smooth system of equations.

I wonder if we get a similar description for symplectic manifolds. It would be nice, for example, if the existence of a non-degenerate two-form added constraint to what the smooth functions that locally describe the manifold can be.

Does someone know?
Thank you.

Comment: What does that description of smooth manifolds gain you over "locally $\mathbb{R}^n$" which is a lot simpler? The difference from the algebraic geometry case is that it's genuinely not true that most varieties are locally affine. Anyway, Darboux's theorem implies that locally all symplectic $2n$-manifolds look like $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ with the standard symplectic form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem

Comment: Simplicity is not the point, the goal is just to have an analogy.  Darboux does not answer the question, as far as I know it does not say something about the smooth map that will cut off the manifold.

Comment: But it's just not an accurate analogy. There are zero sets of smooth functions that are not smooth manifolds. The actual point is to get things that are locally $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: As we know: One and the same smooth manifold can have different Riemannian metrics and (if even dimensional) different symplectic structures. To describe the manifold locally its Riemannian or symplectic structure is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, should have thought of this. Thanks to both of you.